# The installation of an application in the Google play store is stuck on pending. How can I know what is causing it?

Tags: google-play-store

The installation of an application in the Google play store is stuck on pending. How can I know what is causing it?

[image]

Comment: Many reasons - internet issues, server problems, free space on your device, firewall rules (if you sure using), VPN etc //Cancelling and trying in a little while often solved the problem for me

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, I see. I was hoping that Play could be more verbose regarding the issue.

Comment: It does [have](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7513003?hl=en) ;clearing cache of download manager, Play Store etc and few more